# Should it be the controller or the model that handles parameters?

Tags: jakarta-ee, model-view-controller

I have a servlet used to create an account.
I have a question: to me, the controller should be totally independent of request's parameters, but for example if I have a controller method like

```
public User signup(String pseudo, String firstname, String lastname, String password, String email)
```

and i want the user to type his password twice, should I pass the second input as an argument to signup (breaking the "simplicity" of this method) or should I check if the first password matches the second in the servlet (keeping the controller doing only it's job, but making the servlet check inputs) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine that controller is a glue between your view and model(services, daos, etc.). Controller should parse incoming data from the view, pass it to the model, and then return response.

In your case I would check if passwords are equal at page via JavaScript, send data with only one password to controller(servlet), extract in controller required parameters and invoke method from business logic to create account.

Comment: Hum, you're right !

But let's imagine I've got sensible data coming from the client, the verification should be done server-side, and if so should it be the servlet that verify data ? Or I could maybe create a class called by the servlet to assert inputs are not corrupted, and this class could take the request as argument (so it would be strongly bound to the servlet, but it wouldn't matter because it's its role)

Comment: Thüzhen, of course server-side validation is required for every webapp, but I personally don't see the point in validating if both passwords match, as it is not a threat to my webapp data integrity. In your case follow OOP high cohesion principle, and create separate class for HttpServletRequest args parser, and args validator. Have you ever try Spring MVC framework? There is a lot of out of box utils for your concerns.